# SMB slow read/write from Mac workstation vs. Windows

Tags: macos, networking, samba, smb

We have an SMB share running in Hyper-V on Server 2012.

Read/Write to the share from Windows workstations on the network is around 100 MB/s, which seems good.

Read/Write from Mac workstations to the share is half this (50 MB/s) at best. Unfortunately these are the designers working with large files who actually need the network performance.

It's probably not a networking hardware issue, as iperf tests from my Mac to the server show over 117MB/s bandwidth. To clarify, this is an issue specific to using the SMB protocol from the Mac.

Comment: This a new problem or an existing problem?

Comment: This is an existing problem; send/receive rates between Macs and the SMB share has never been good.

Comment: Does the workstations have 10/100 ports or 10/100/1000 ports?  If you use the same LAN cable as a working station what happens?   The fact it is a 50% decrease indicates an overall problem

Comment: It's probably not a networking hardware issue, as iperf tests from my Mac to the server show over 117MB/s bandwidth. To clarify, this is an issue specific to using the SMB protocol from the Mac.

Comment: Make sure all your Macs are running Mavericks (OS X 10.9.x) or later. The built-in SMB client in OS X only supported SMB 1.x until Mavericks, and there were some big speed boosts in SMB 2.x.

Comment: The Mac in question is running Yosemite with latest updates.

Comment: @PyroLemur - Update the question to reflect that information.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out.

Running `smbutil statshares -m /Volumes/MyShare/` revealed that the Mac's connection to the SMB share was negotiated using SMB1.

I then looked at ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf and noticed that it contained the following:

```
[default]
smb_neg=smb1_only
```

After deleting this and running smbutil again, I can see the share is negotiating using SMB3.02, and the performance seems to have increased to where it should be.